# PHP: exif_imagetype() not letting me upload any type of image?

Tags: php, image

I'm trying to restrict uploaded files with PHP, only to certain types of images.
This is what I've tried:

This is the form input field:

```
<input type="file" id="dni" name="dni">
```

And this is the checkout process:

```
if (exif_imagetype($_FILES['dni']["name"]) != IMAGETYPE_GIF || IMAGETYPE_JPEG || IMAGETYPE_PNG) {
    echo 'Only images!';
    exit;
}
```

I've tried using `$_FILES['dni']["name"]` and `$_FILES['dni']["tmp_name"]`

And as maybe my condition was not writter in a proper way, I've also tried:

```
if (exif_imagetype($_FILES['dni']["name"]) != IMAGETYPE_GIF) { ...
```

And after that I've tried to upload a gif image.

I've tried to upload gif and jpeg images and I keep receiving an error (the "Only images!" message).

### **UPDATE:**

I've modified the code, and still won't work:

```
if (exif_imagetype($_FILES['dni']['name']) != IMAGETYPE_GIF 
        AND exif_imagetype($_FILES['dni']['name']) != IMAGETYPE_JPEG 
        AND exif_imagetype($_FILES['dni']['name']) != IMAGETYPE_PNG) {
        echo 'Only images!';
    exit;
}
```

Comment: You should probably avoid calling `exif_imagetype` more than once. It has to open the file and read the beginning every time you call it. Something like `in_array(exif_imagetype(...), array(IMAGETYPE_GIF, IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_PNG))` should be faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not comparing them right, try this:

```
if (exif_imagetype($_FILES["dni"]["tmp_name"]) != IMAGETYPE_GIF && exif_imagetype($_FILES["dni"]["tmp_name"]) != IMAGETYPE_JPEG && exif_imagetype($_FILES["dni"]["tmp_name"]) != IMAGETYPE_PNG) {
    echo 'Only images!';
    exit;
}
```

You used || (OR) instead of && (AND). It needs to display the error if the imagetype does not equal all those. If you use an OR it will always display it because it can't be all those types at once.

Also, seems $_FILES["dni"]["tmp_name"] is correct. Try changing your ' to a "

Comment: I thought that, but it won't work even if I try just one type of images.

Comment: I'm reworking my answer, the ||'s are wrong also. Right now it displays it always, because for example if it's a PNG then "filetype != GIF" for example will already set it off.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've just tried that (with the AND operator) and can't make it work either.

Comment: I've never really worked with `exif_imagetype` so it should be an error in there. But conditionally the IF statement is correct now.

Comment: I looked up the exif_imagetype function and your IF statement is correct as it is. The problem is very likely the `$_FILES['dni']["name"]` part. Are you sure the file is correctly being posted to your PHP? Also, seems `$_FILES["dni"]["tmp_name"]` is correct. Try changing your ' to a ".

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Yes, I've tried changing the single quotes for the double quotes and there's still the issue.

Comment: @rosamunda No problem! Be sure to mark the answer with the checkmark! :)